# Generate SSH key for Public Key Authentication

Tags: ssh, public-key, ssh-keygen, key-generator

Customer is changing SFTP to different location and written to me.

```
Changing SFTP-server to a more modern service at AWS. 
Would be to secure the new username with a SSH key pair, 
as we’re trying to get rid of all the password usage in the new service. 
Could you deliver us a public key for this?
```

I have no understanding of this.
What actually I need to do here? Is it following ssh-keygen command? Do i need to share QA and Production separately?

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-with-key

Comment: What you need to do is talk to the customer and tell them that you have no understanding of this.

Comment: Informed !!! :)